# loop through python months since start time

Tags: python, date

I want to loop through the months since a given start time, and print the first and last day. I can manually keep track of which month and year it is, and use the calendar.monthrange(year, month) to get the number of days...but is that the best way?

```
from datetime import date
start_date = date(2010, 8, 1)
end_date = date.today()
# I want to loop through each month and print the first and last day of the month
# 2010, 8, 1 to 2010, 8, 31
# 2010, 9, 1 to 2010, 9, 30
# ....
# 2011, 3, 1 to 2011, 3, 31
# 2011, 4, 1, to 2011, 4, 12 (ends early because it is today)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the last day of a month, you can use first_of_next_month - datetime.timedelta(1).  For instance:

```
def enumerate_month_dates(start_date, end_date):
    current = start_date
    while current <= end_date:
        if current.month >= 12:
            next = datetime.date(current.year + 1, 1, 1)
        else:
            next = datetime.date(current.year, current.month + 1, 1)
        last = min(next - datetime.timedelta(1), end_date)
        yield current, last
        current = next
```

Answer (score 0):

the dateutil module does support such operations, see: http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the Gregorian calendar, the first day of any month is numbered 1 and the last day is the first of next month minus one. Thus, in its most trivial form:

```
d = datetime.date(2010, m, 1)
print d, datetime.date(2010, m + 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

(this doesn't work in December as the month argument to date() needs to be in 1..12)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with first day of the start date
2. Calculate number of days in that month and get start of next month
3. print start date and (start of next month - 1 day)

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import date, timedelta
import calendar
start_date = date(2001,8,1)
end_date = date.today()
while True:
    if start_date > end_date:
        break
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month)[1]  # Calculate days in month for start_date
    new_ts = calendar.timegm(start_date.timetuple()) + (days_in_month * 24 * 60 * 60)  # Get timestamp for start of next month
    new_start_date = date(1,1,1).fromtimestamp(new_ts) # Convert timestamp to date object
    print start_date, new_start_date - timedelta(1)
    start_date = new_start_date
```